# How can we import the image from one js file to another js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import the image from one js file to another js file.
My first js file is as function component **Track.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { screenimage, screenimage1 } from "./srcimages.js";

function Track() {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello Component
            <img src={screenimage} alt=""/>
            <img src={screenimage1} alt=""/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Track
```

My second js file is as const **image.js**

```js
const screenimage = 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/shopping-online-concept-modern-design-260nw-1934432345.jpg';
const screenimage1 = 'https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png';
```

I am trying to make a collection of multiple image source in one js file and import it as img `<img src={here}/>` attribute. I tried the above method but it's showing empty value of src.

**UPDATE**
Remove the tag "typoscript" from this post

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the tag "typoscript", or even "typescript" for that matter.  Can you remove it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the images from the `image.js` file. Check the code below:

```js
export const screenimage = "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/shopping-online-concept-modern-design-260nw-1934432345.jpg";
export const screenimage1 = "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

So try add the export behind the `const`

like

```
export const screenimage = 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/shopping-online-concept-modern-design-260nw-1934432345.jpg',
```